# subset a dataframe by complicate conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to ask a R expert to write a concise code to subset two dataframes from a data frame. My data frame `df` looks like:

```
 mi     chr    bin   A       B       C       D     sum  QS
m004775 Ch01    1   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m004776 Ch01    1   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m027081 Ch01    4   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    2   1
m027082 Ch01    4   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m025498 Ch01    4   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    2   1
m025500 Ch01    6   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    3   1
m027084 Ch01    6   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    2   NA
m027088 Ch01    6   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    3   2
m004820 Ch01    6   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m004827 Ch01    7   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m004828 Ch01    7   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   1
m004830 Ch01    7   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    2   NA
m004859 Ch01    7   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   2   NA
m025511 Ch01    9   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   2   1
m004946 Ch01    9   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   2   NA
m004947 Ch01    9   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m027141 Ch01    9   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    3   1
m027156 Ch01    9   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   3   NA
m027163 Ch01    9   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m027165 Ch01    9   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   3   2
m027200 Ch01    10  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   3   NA
m005105 Ch01    10  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    4   1
```

the expected subset data frame `df1`

```
 mi     chr    bin  A       B       C       D      sum  QS
m027081 Ch01    4   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    2   1
m025500 Ch01    6   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    3   1
m004828 Ch01    7   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   1
m027141 Ch01    9   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    3   1
m027165 Ch01    9   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   3   2
m005105 Ch01    10  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    4   1
```

the expected subset data frame `df2`

```
 mi     chr    bin  A       B       C       D      sum  QS
m004775 Ch01    1   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m004820 Ch01    6   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   1   NA
m004830 Ch01    7   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    2   NA
m004859 Ch01    7   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   2   NA
```

The rows for subset have to meet the following rules:
For each bin (column `bin`: levels `1, 2, 3, …,20`) of each group (column `chr1`: levels `ch01, ch02, …,ch20`):

1. if columns `A`, `B`,`C` or `D` has `TRUE` value, select as few as possible of row(s) with as many `TRUE` as possible in columns `A`, `B` ,`C` and `D` (the number of `TRUE` values across the columns is column `sum`);
2. If the value in column `QS` is a numeric (values: `1`, `2` or `3`, the priority order for selecting: `1` > `2`> `3`); the selected rows go to `df1`;
3. If the value in column `QS` is `NA`, following the same rule as Rule 1, the selected rows go to `df2`, and if the bin has row(s) already selected for the respective column `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`, there is no selection for this bin in `df2`.

I did this selection manually. First, sorting  the dataframe by column `QS` to separate numeric and `NA`, then sorting the numeric block by `chr`,`bin`,`sum` (decreasing order), `QS`(increasing order), then select the top one for each bin. If rows with `4` in `sum` selected, those bins are done, if rows with `3`, `2` or `1` are selected, I need to find if other rows in the same bin can be selected.  Then move to the `NA` block to do the similar selection but if rows in the same bin for corresponding columns `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` with `TRUE` value have been selected in the numeric block, there is no selection in the `NA` block.
It is too complicate and time consuming to work with a big data frame. If someone can help me with R code, that would save me a lot of time.  Thank you for any helps.

Comment: I can't see why you have two rows for `bin=9` in output `df1` but only one row for `bin=4`? Excluding the `bin=4` row with `QS=NA` from `df` (rule 3), the two remaining `bin=4` rows are identical (same `QS`, same `sum`). So I don't understand your rule 2.

Comment: actually I'm not sure I understand rule 1 any more - does it just mean select rows where sum is the max(sum) over that `bin` group? I'm not sure where "as few as possible" comes in.

Comment: So if one row has TTFF and the other has FFTT you take both so that together there's  TRUEs in all of A,B,C, and D? But if both rows have TTFF then you only take one because taking both will only give you TRUEs for A and B (and not C and D)? (Considering a two-row system for simplicity)

Comment: `as few as possible` means select `max(sum)`. if `max(sum)`<4 then you need to see if other row(s) could be selected to compliment `FALSE` in the selected `max(sum)`

Comment: what is the rule to select m027081 over m025498? precedence?